# Get default border of JButton

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

How can I get the default border of a `JButton`?

An example is:

```
Border border = new JButton().getBorder();
```

But can I do it without creating a new button?

Comment: I think nobody really understands your question.

Comment: I am making a game where i have JButtons representing my pieces. When i click one i want it to change border into LineBorder, and if i click it again, i want the default border.

I fixed it with using my getBorder(), but would prefer to just type in the border which is default

Comment: This sounds like you need to use JToggleButton instead of JButton.

Comment: I've clarify the question and it should be answerable now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve the default border from `UIManager`:

```
UIManager.getBorder("Button.border");
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestButton {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestButton");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Button.border"));
            }
        });

        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```